# if $n$ is natural odd number then the polynom : $P(x)=x^n+ax^2+b$ has at the most 3 different roots

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, roots

I have this problem :

if $n$ is natural odd number then the polynom : $P(x)=x^n+ax^2+b$ has at the most 3 different roots.

$$P(x)=x^n+ax^2+b$$
$$P'(x)=nx^{n-1}+2ax$$
$$P''(x)=n(n-1)x^{n-2}+2a$$

I understand that I need to use Rolle's theorem in order to proof it, but I don't understand why P''(x) has only one root? why doesn't P''(x) has more roots than one?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean, and should say, the roots need to be real, I guess.

Comment: @mathlove Thank you edited.

Comment: @quid I don't understand why it has only one root, There's a theorem that says that any polynom with odd power has atleast one real root, but how can I know there's just one and not more?

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: You can solve $P''(x)=0$ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $$P''(x)=n(n-1)x^{n-2}+2a$$

But $x^{n-2}$ is strictly increasing, so $P''$ is strictly increasing, so $P''$ can have at most one zero. It also clearly has at least one root.

Comment: I agree that $P''$ has only one root, but if I keep derivative I can get that $P'''$ also has one root like in this example : $$P(x)=x5+2x2+1$$
$$P′(x)=5x4+4x$$
$$P′′(x)=20x3+4$$
$$P′′′(x)=60x2$$ since $P'''$ has a root I could conclude with Rolle's theorem that P has at most four different roots, in contradiction to the proof.

Comment: Why? It does have at most four roots. The fact that it can't have four roots doesn't contradict anything. I have at most 10,000 fingers. @JaVaPG

Comment: But, $P'''(x)$ has a root in $x=0$, using Rolle's theorem I can conclude that $P''(x)$ has at most two different roots and $P'(x)$ has at most three different roots and $P(x)$ has at most four different roots. but the question asks to proof that $P(x)$ has at most three differents roots and I found that $P(x)$ has at most four differents roots in contradiction to the question request.

Comment: But we know $P''$ has at most $1$ root by my argument. So $P'$ has at most $2$ roots, and thus $P$ has at most $3$ roots. There is no contradiction between these roots, because $3<4$. If I *actually* have $4$ roots, then yes, this would be a contradiction, but Rolle does let you prove that there are four roots.

Comment: You keep insisting there is a contradiction between the statements "$P$ has at most $3$ roots" and $P$ has at most $4$ roots." There is no contradiction. There would be if the two statements were "$P$ has at most $3$ roots" and "$P$ can have $4$ roots." But that is not what we've shown.

Comment: How many roots does $x^4+1$ have? None. Yet Rolle's theorem would say that there are at most $2$ roots, since $4x^3$ has one root. That's not a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand that is not a contradiction to the question but how do you know that $P(x)$ doesn't have 4 different roots? or in other words how do you know that $P$ can't have 4 roots?

Comment: @JaVaPG Because I proved that $P''$ has at most $1$ zero, so $P$ has at most $3$ roots! I've proved a *stronger result.* Being able to prove a weaker result (at most $4$ roots) doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: This might be something you need to sleep on, because it really isn't that hard. Maybe you've been thinking about the problem too long and are getting disoriented. It happens to mathematicians all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative can only have one real root as $n-2$ is odd, and every real number has a unique *real* $n-2$th root.

And the problem amounts to finding a real number such that $x^{n-2}$ equals $\frac{-2a}{n(n-1)}$. So the solution is $$\sqrt[n-2]{\frac{-2a}{n(n-1)}}$$ or 
$$\text{sign}(a) \, \sqrt[n-2]{\frac{|2a|}{n(n-1)}}$$
depending on ones conventions.

Comment: Lets assume that n=5 and : $$f(x)=x^5+2x^2+1$$ $$f'(x)=5x^4+4x$$ $$f''(x)=20x^3+4$$ $$f'''(x)=60x^2$$, therefore the 3rd derivative has real root which is $0$, therefore using Rolle's the 2nd derivative could have at most 2 different roots, and the 1st derivative could have 3 different roots, and f(x) could have 4 differents roots, in contradiction to what you said, can you please explain?

Comment: You can rewrite $20 x^3 + 4 = 0$ as $x^3 = -4/20$. So the only solution is *the* real third root of $-1/5$. If you want to show that roots are unique and exist, note that $x^n$ is stricly increasing and surjective for odd $n$.

Comment: But zero is also a real root, The point of the example was to show that I could go the 3rd derivative and will be able to find real root I don't understand why you "stop" at the 2nd derivative? If I go to the 3rd derivative I can conclude that f(x) has at most 4 differents roots as written above.

Comment: I "stop" at the second derivative because you asked about it.  Do you agree that $1.25992\ldots$ is the third root of $2$? What does it mean that something is a third root of $2$ and why is this uniquely defined? Why do you see a problem doing the same thing for $-1/5$?

Answer (score 0):

Equal $P'(x)=nx^{n-1}+2ax$ to $0$ and find two point. (Suppose $a\not=0$)

$x_1=0$ and $x_2= \sqrt[n-2]{-2a}$ (Minima and maxima, or maxima and minima because $n-2$ is odd)

Suppose $x_1>x_2$

We now that $lim_{x \to +\infty}P(x)=+\infty$ and $ lim_{x \to -\infty}P(x)=-\infty$ So $x_1$ is a maxima and $x_2$ is a minima and $P(x_1)>P(x_2)$ (in $(x_1,x_2)$  $P(x)$ is strictly decreasing)

1. If $P(x_1)>0$ and $P(x_2)<0$  there are a root $z_0 \in (-\infty,x_1)$, a root $z_1 \in (x_1,x_2)$, a root $z_2 \in (x_2,+\infty)$
2. If $P(x_1)>0$ and $P(x_2)>0$  there is a root $z_0 \in (-\infty,x_1)$
3. If $P(x_1)<0$ and $P(x_2)<0$  there is a root $z_0 \in (x_2,+\infty)$

Analog for $x_1<x_2$

If $x_1=x_2 → a=0$ So we have that $x=0$ is a flex (the unique one) for $P(x)=x^n+b$ so there is only one root  $x_0=\sqrt[n]{-b}$